# Context is null in service constructor?

Tags: android, android-service, android-context

My goal is to have a background service that update a fairly large amount of data twice a day (~5min update, possibly more).

So I have a GcmTaskService that launch this service :

```
public class SyncOfflineCoursesService extends Service {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new MonBinder();
    private final SharedPreferenceManagerToReplace sharedPreferenceManager;

    public SyncOfflineCoursesService() {

        sharedPreferenceManager = new SharedPreferenceManagerToReplace(this); //crash on this line

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class MonBinder extends Binder {
        SyncOfflineCoursesService getService() {
            return SyncOfflineCoursesService.this;
        }
    }

}
```

`SharedPreferenceManagerToReplace` :

```
public class SharedPreferenceManagerToReplace {
    private final SharedPreferences prefs;

    public SharedPreferenceManagerToReplace(Context context) {
        this.prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);//crash here
    }
}
```

but it seem that this is null when I instanciate `SharedPreferenceManager`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
```

That's how I declared both of my services in my manifest :

```
<service
    android:name=".service.offline.SyncOfflineCoursesService"
    android:exported="false" />

<service
    android:name=".service.offline.SyncOfflineContentService"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.gms.permission.BIND_NETWORK_TASK_SERVICE">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_TASK_READY" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Would you have an idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: use application level context for this

Comment: Your `Service` shouldn't really have a constructor. Move that initialization to one of its lifecycle methods, like `onCreate()` or `onStartCommand()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> NullPointerException is thrown when an application attempts to use an
>   object reference that has the null value.

You should call this in **[onStartCommand()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int))** Section .

```
 Context context;  //Public  

 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
    {
    context= getApplicationContext();
    sharedPreferenceManager = new SharedPreferenceManagerToReplace(context); 
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks a lot. By the way would you confirm that launching a service from a GcmTaskService is the best way to download large amount of data every 10 hours ?

Comment: what kind of requirements ? what are the alternatives ?

Comment: Heavy mean between few Ko to Go of data (it syncrhonises Courses that are made available to offline and may contain all sort of medias (so videos too))

Comment: @RenaudFavier then  download large amount of data every 10 hours

Answer (score 0):

You should have context of an activity. Context of service won't work.
In constructor pass the context and use that context to pass along the next constructor.

```
public SyncOfflineCoursesService(Context mContext) {

     sharedPreferenceManager = new SharedPreferenceManagerToReplace(mContext); 

}
```

Comment: Hello and thanks ! there is no activity when the service is created (it's created from the GCMTaskService)